# Can't get file name and extension in variable in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, pathinfo

Can't get file name and extension in the variable "$fileNameToStore" but it is able to save default image name {'noimage.jpg'} in database.
i want to know what is the cause for that.

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'img' => 'nullable|max:1999'
            // 'phone' => 'required'
        ]);


        //handle file

        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';

        if($request->hasFile('img')){
            //get file name and extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('img')->getClientOriginalName();
            //get just file name
            $filename = $request->file('img')->getClientOriginalName();
            //get just extension
            $extension = $request->file('img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //file name to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //upload the image
            $path = $request->file('img')->storeAs('public/product_images', $fileNameToStore);
        }



        //create product

        $product = new Product;
        $product->type = $request->input('type');
        $product->img = $fileNameToStore;
        $product->details = $request->input('details');
        $product->save();


        $notification = array(
                'message' => 'Ürün kaydedildi !',
                'alert-type' => 'success'
            );

        return redirect('/urungir')->with($notification);
    }
```

Comment: what gives you `dd($fileNameToStore);`?

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal" action="/products" method="post" enctype="multipart/data" id="urungirform">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="file" name="img">
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this issue is that, in the form that submits to the controller, there is a mistake as shown below, The  `enctype="multipart/data"` is wrong and in order to fix the problem, it should change to:  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```php
// Wrong :
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/products" method="post" enctype="multipart/data" id="urungirform"> 
    {{ csrf_field() }} 
    <input type="file" name="img"> 
</form>

// Correct :
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/products" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="urungirform"> 
    {{ csrf_field() }} 
    <input type="file" name="img"> 
</form>
```